# get all aws account numbers and exclude those which are passed during the execution of script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jq, terraform-provider-aws

I want to apply certain SCP (service control policies) to all  AWS accounts under organization except the one specified by account owners.

for attaching SCP policy to aws account ,I am using terraform's below resource:

```
resource "aws_organizations_policy_attachment" "account" {
  for_each  = toset(var.aws_account_number_restrict_root_scp)
  policy_id = aws_organizations_policy.restrict_root.id
  target_id = each.key
}

#aws_account_number_restrict_root_scp should evaluates to something like this:
#["33333443453","333333333333","444444444444"]
```

now I want to generate  `aws_account_number_restrict_root_scp` variable through any scripting language.
which will be all  AWS accounts numbers under AWS organization except the one specified by account owners.
the variable should be in above mentioned format.

I am getting all the aws account numbers in required format using below, but not able to remove the one provided by the account owners.

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo $0
var=$(aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[*].Id')
echo $var
```

How to filter `$var` by removing the account numbers provided by the account owner?

In simple words,

```
var=[
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "JoinedMethod": "INVITED",
    "Id": "3234443322122"
  },
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "Name": "ABC",
    "JoinedMethod": "CREATED",
    "Id": "12345678901"
  },
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "Name": "PQR",
    "JoinedMethod": "CREATED",
    "Id": "3444550998293"
  }
]

exception=["3444550998293"]

#then expected result should be:
echo $expected_output
[
"3234443322122",
 "12345678901"
]
```

note: `$var` is generated run time and have more than 200 elements and `$exception` is user expected data.

Comment: So you want to filter the array with other array using bash?

Comment: yes.but expected output is something json like format. not array.
expected output: `["33333333333","233222233232"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a filter which uses [`index/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#index(s),rindex(s))

```
map( .Id | select( . as $id | $exception | index($id) | not ) )
```

To use it you need to provide an **exception** array.
One way is to use `--argjson` e.g. if your filter is in `filter.jq`

`jq -Mc --argjson exception '["3444550998293"]' -f filter.jq <<< "${var}"`

Sample output

```
["3234443322122","12345678901"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBNi8IwEIbv/RVD6MGCSpu0ar3V2kMEZbcr4gceQhu0oonaCMLu/vZsquhBWdDDHN7nHXiY2Ry03rF9DZo0hx8o@ZZnyiRgJdhFhWx@zvheFVKYUIicn2umcEwQUoEDjqX1wgL4NgOAvhRTpxJ1AUXxmE4SVL/yEdvxik5n8xsayELwfMjVWuZVRUcTOk76t5peIMHE931CMPYwRqb5rb8ui3rxf7I4TaInmWdkQavdCV3vXdXHZ/qWqroqCNww7OCQXGTWUjca7LjalFLo@9P14mHVbA2zPw)

Comment: declared array is : $exception=["3444550998293"] getting below error: jq: error: exception/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1: map( .Id | select( . as $id | $exception | index($id) | not ) ) jq: 1 compile error –

Comment: after making little changes , it worked. Many thanks @jq170727

exception=["3444550998293"] 
echo $var | jq -c --arg exception "$exception" \
 'map( .Id |  select( . as $id | $exception | index($id) | not ) )'